# Prove the theorem of Egoroff

Tags: measure-theory

> > (Theorem of **Egoroff.)** Let $(\Omega,\mathfrak{A},\mu)$ be a measure space with finite mesaure $\mu$. Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real-valued, measurable functions that converges a.s. to a real-valued and mesaurable function $f$. Then for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a measurable set $A\in\mathfrak{A}$ with $\mu(\Omega\setminus A)<\varepsilon$, so that $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly on $A$.

Hello, I tried to prove that.

I use the fact that from convergence a.s. it follows convergence stochastically (local), i.e. for all $A\in\mathcal{A}$ with $\mu(A)<\infty$ and all $\varepsilon > 0$ it is
$$
\mu(A\cap\left\{\lvert f_n-f\rvert\geq\varepsilon\right\})\to 0, n\to\infty.
$$

*Proof*

Because $(f_n)$ converges a.s. to $f$ it follows: For any $k\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists a $N_k\in\mathbb{N}$ so that
$$
\mu(\underbrace{\left\{\omega\in\Omega: \forall n\geq N_k: \lvert f_n(\omega)-f(\omega)\rvert\geq k^{-1}\right\}}_{=:E_k^C})\leq2^{-k}.
$$
$E_k^C$ is measurable. It follows that $\mu(E_k)=\mu(\Omega\setminus E_k^C)\geq\mu(\Omega)-2^{-k}.$

Choose $\tilde{k}$ so large that $\sum_{n=\tilde{k}}^{\infty} 2^{-n}<\varepsilon$ and define
$$
A:=\bigcap_{n\geq\tilde{k}}E_n.
$$
Then $A\in\mathcal{A}$ and
$$
\mu(\Omega\setminus A)<\varepsilon.
$$

So I think that $A$ is the set that the theorem says it exists.

But what's about the uniformly convergence of $(f_n)$ on my defined $A$?

I think because $A\subset E_n~\forall n\geq\tilde{k}$ one can set
$$
N:=\max_{n\geq\tilde{k}}\left\{N_n\right\}
$$
and then for all $\omega\in A$; for all $n\geq N$ and for all $\varepsilon >0$ it is
$$
\lvert f_n(\omega)-f(\omega)\rvert<\varepsilon,
$$
which means that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $A$.

Am I right?

Greetings

Miro

Comment: There is a good proof in Royden.

Comment: Do not now have access to that book unfortunately.

Comment: I think you mean $\mu(\Omega\setminus A)<\epsilon$

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry. I correct it!